# Deadlock after MPI::COMM::Create (all processes terminate) 

Tags: c++, mpi

**Problem:**

I'm writing MPI programm using MPI C++ binding (MPICH 2). After specific amount of calling function listed below I get deadlock right after calling `MPI::COMM::Create` method (all running processes terminate).

`LOCAL_COMM = LOCAL_COMM.Create(localGroup)` in the code, need to be more specific.

My guess is that some kind of overflow appears,  but I'm new to MPI programming and can`t find the source of problem. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Code:**

```
 Matrix Matrix::operator* (Matrix &M)
{
    //Synchronize all threads
    //COMM_WORLD.Barrier();

    int hisCol = M.myCol;
    int commSize = COMM_WORLD.Get_size();

    //Create local Group and Communicator equal to COMM_WORLD
    Intracomm LOCAL_COMM = COMM_WORLD.Dup();
    Group localGroup(LOCAL_COMM.Get_group());

    //Change locals if required
    if(commSize > myRow) {
        //Make array of ranks to include
        vector<int> masRanks(myRow);
        for(int i = 0; i < myRow; i++)
            masRanks[i] = i;

        //Create new localGroup and LOCAL_COMM
        localGroup = localGroup.Incl(myRow,&masRanks[0]);
        LOCAL_COMM = LOCAL_COMM.Create(localGroup); 
        if(LOCAL_COMM == COMM_NULL) {
            localGroup.Free();
            return Matrix(myRow,hisCol);
        }
        commSize = LOCAL_COMM.Get_size();
    }

    //Calculate number of Rows displacement and amount to Send per Thread
    vector<int> masRows(commSize,0);
    vector<int> amntToSend(commSize,0), amntToRecv(commSize,0);
    int tmpRows = myRow;

    for(int i = commSize; i > 0; i--) {
        masRows[i-1] = ((double)tmpRows / i + 0.5);
        tmpRows -= masRows[i-1];

        amntToSend[i-1] = masRows[i-1] * myCol;
        amntToRecv[i-1] = masRows[i-1] * hisCol;
    }

    //Form array specifying displacement to send to each thread
    vector<int> elemDisp(1,0), elemRecvDisp(1,0);
    if(myRank == 0)         
        for(int i = 1; i < commSize; i++) {
                elemDisp.push_back(amntToSend[i-1] + elemDisp[i-1]);
                elemRecvDisp.push_back(amntToRecv[i-1] + elemRecvDisp[i-1]);
        }

    //Prepare variables and send / receive left and right matrix
    int maxRow = *max_element(masRows.begin(),masRows.end());

    Matr tmpData(maxRow*myCol,0);
    LOCAL_COMM.Scatterv(&data[0],&amntToSend[0],&elemDisp[0],DOUBLE,&tmpData[0],masRows[myRank]*myCol,DOUBLE,0);
    LOCAL_COMM.Bcast(&M.data[0],M.myRow*hisCol,DOUBLE,0);

    //Start evaluation of each element
    Matr resData(masRows[myRank]*hisCol,0);
    for(int row = 0; row < masRows[myRank]; row++)
        for(int i = 0; i < hisCol; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < myCol; j++)
                resData[row*hisCol + i] += tmpData[row*myCol + j] * M.data[j*hisCol + i];

    //Gather all data at 0-thread
    Matr outData(myRow*hisCol);
    LOCAL_COMM.Gatherv(&resData[0],masRows[myRank]*hisCol,DOUBLE,&outData[0],&amntToRecv[0],&elemRecvDisp[0],DOUBLE,0);

    //Return result Matrix-object
    Matrix resMatr(myRow, hisCol);
    resMatr.data = outData;

    //Free group and communicator
    localGroup.Free();
    LOCAL_COMM.Free();

    return resMatr;
}
```

Comment: What is a "Matr", and what does this constructor do? `Matr tmpData(maxRow*myCol,0);`. That might be a problem, depending on what that 0 means. I'd suggest you to run this application using valgrind, you will be able to spot buffer overflows and another memory issues easily that way.

Comment: where does `myRow` come from? Can you be sure that all MPI processes share the same value for `myRow`? If not, they won't be building the same local group, and the call to `MPI_Comm_create` will fail.

Comment: myRow is the amount of Rows in a matrix class, so yes all threads share the same value. Moreover it takes about 2000 function calls (I mean operator*()) to get termination of all processes.

Comment: If you solved it, make your solution an actual answer and accept it. Don't change your title to include [solved].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the problem was in a way that I created new Group and Communicator. Perhaps COMM_WORLD.Dup() was the wrong choice from the very beginning since I don`t really know what compiler do with it's value after leaving the function.

Anyway corrected code is listed below.

**Fixed Code:**

```
Matrix Matrix::operator* (Matrix &M)
{
    int hisCol = M.myCol;
    int commSize = COMM_WORLD.Get_size();

    //Make array of ranks to include
    vector<int> vRanks;
    for(int i = 0; i < myRow && i < commSize; i++)
        vRanks.push_back(i);

    //Create new LocalGroup and LOCAL_COMM
    Group LocalGroup = COMM_WORLD.Get_group().Incl(vRanks.size(),&vRanks[0]);
    Intracomm LOCAL_COMM = COMM_WORLD.Create(LocalGroup);

    COMM_WORLD.Barrier();

    //Make unused processes quit
    if(LOCAL_COMM == COMM_NULL) {
        LocalGroup.Free();
        return Matrix(myRow,hisCol);
    }
    commSize = LOCAL_COMM.Get_size();

    //The rest is pretty much the same
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious, but unhelpful, answer is that you have written a program which deadlocks.  Arguably this is much easier than writing one which is deadlock-free.

Have you investigated any of the tools which might help you find your problem ?  Tools such as:

[Vampir](http://www.vampir.eu/)

Intel's [Trace Analyzer](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-trace-analyzer/) (which may actually be based on Vampir)

or the parallel debuggers

RogueWave's [TotalView](http://www.roguewave.com/products/totalview.aspx)

Allinea's [DDT](http://www.allinea.com/products/ddt/)

At least one of these should be in your parallel programming toolbox.